# cakephp - view with data from multiple tables

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

i am working on a Cakephp 2.x. I have two tables in my app: 'Images' and 'Audios'... i have a view in which i want to show the images and videos both sorted by date ... dont know how to do this ... because the main problem is in Cakephp if you want to show image we do this

```
echo $data['Image']['filename'];
```

and for audio i do this

```
echo $data['Audio']['filename'];
```

we have to specify the modal name specifically.. but now i dont want to do this.. i want to show in random sorted by date.. for example if today someone uploaded an image and yesterday an audio was uploaded ... so the data has to look like this on the view page

```
audio.mp3 ,image.jpg .....so on
```

like this ..

i dont want to write like this

```
foreach($datas as $data){
    echo $data['Image']['filename'];
    echo $data['Audio']['filename'];
}
```

here i am explicitly telling that image comes first and then the audio which i dont want ...

**my Images Model**

```
function getImagesAndAudio($userid){
    $this->bindModel(array(
        'belongsTo' => array(
            'Audio' => array(
                'className' => 'Audio',
                'foreignKey' => false,
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Image.user_id = Audio.user_id',
                ),
                'type' => 'LEFT',
            )
        )
    ), false);

    return $this->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Image.User_id' => $userid),
        'contain' => array('Audio' ),
    ));
}
```

passing data from controller like this

```
$data = $this->Image->getImagesAndAudio($userid);
$this->set('datas', $data);
```

Comment: I think it would be more relevant to have a Document Model that belongsTo User and in which you would save your Images and Audio files sorting them eventually with a "type" field. That way you wouldn't have to worry about your data type as the field that interests you for Images and Audio is the same : 'filename'. Moreover you would not need to do that bindModel with a LEFT join in your Images Model which does not make much sense IMO.

Comment: @Chris thankyou ... i am new to cakephp can you give me an example of this ...

Comment: Well you are not far from it with the code you have posted: create a documents table with the right columns (you want to have 'filename', 'user_id' that were allready present and probably 'type' to determine if the file is audio or image) ; create the Document Model whith belongsTo => array('User') (actually this is optional, but it's for constistency) , do a find('all') on your Documents and then in your view you just echo $data['Document']['filename'] without wondering what type of file you are linking to.

Comment: I think Chris is right. In your case it's best to redesign your models, but for others looking for a solution where that's not possible here's a similar question: [Combining lists of data from Multiple Models and sort them by date created in cakephp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13158565/combining-lists-of-data-from-multiple-models-and-sort-them-by-date-created-in-ca)

Comment: @Corie thankyou very much ... this was exactly what i was needed,the link you share