# Combine Two Different Models in Array for Sorting, Referenced Models Lost

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I have two Models, News and Projects. News has a referenced Model, Section. Project has a referenced Model, SubGroup. Both News and Project have a "created" field. I'd like to display on my home page last 5 News *or* Project items.

So I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13158565/combining-lists-of-data-from-multiple-models-and-sort-them-by-date-created-in-ca) post, and did what it said, namely:

```
$newsAndProjects = array();

$news = $this->News->find( ... );
foreach ($news as $k => $v) {
    $newsAndProjects[] = $v['News'];
}

$projects = $this->Project->find( ... );
foreach ($projects as $k => $v) {
    $newsAndProjects[] = $v['Project'];
}

if (sizeof($newsAndProjects) > 1) {
    $newsAndProjects = Set::sort($newsAndProjects, '/created', 'DESC');
}
```

And I thought it worked fine. But when I try to access the referenced Models of News or Project, I get an error.

What I've noticed is, whereas I used to be able to do this:

```
$news['News']['title']
$news['News']['Section']
```

or

```
$projects['Project']['title']
$projects['Project']['SubGroup']
```

... once in the $newsAndProjects array, I have to access the Models directly, namely:

```
$newsAndProjects['title']
```

And I no longer even have 'Section' or 'SubGroup' Models, but rather:

```
$newsAndProjects['section_id']
$newsAndProjects['sub_group_id']
```

... which means I can no longer, for example, access the Section or SubGroup name, id, etc.

How can I get this info back?

Answer (score 1):

What a dummy. I figured it out. My unfamiliarity with Cake and arrays in php in general was the problem.

My referenced Models weren't showing up because I was doing this

```
$newsAndProjects[] = $v['News'];
$newsAndProjects[] = $v['Project'];
```

instead of this

```
$newsAndProjects[] = $v;
$newsAndProjects[] = $v;
```

ie. I was only putting the 'root' Model (News or Project) in the $newsAndProjects array, instead of $v, the *entire* Model object with its corresponding referenced Models.

Hopefully this post will save someone some time someday.